# Getting [Object Object] in local storage

Tags: javascript

I am currently busy with a registration form, I got everything set up nicely, however, I am running into 2 local storage issues.

1. I get the `VM6858:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` error
2. When I click register, something stores in the local storage, but not sure what.

The reason I want to make the information stored in local storage is so that it can be checked when the user signs in on the sign in page.

I am aware PHP is a good combination to do this for server-side, but for now, I am just focusing on storing it on the web browser, this is not being used for people to actually register this is just to practice using local storage in various ways.

HTML

```
<main>
  <div class="heading">
         <h1>User Registration</h1>
    </div>

    <form class="form-container">
      <ul>
      <li><label for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="name" type="text" name="name" required />
      </li>

      <li><label for="surname">Surname</label>
        <input class="surname" type="text" name="surname" required />
      </li>

      <li><label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input class="phone" type="text" name="phone" />
      </li>

      <li><label for="email">Email</label>
      <input class="email" type="text" name="email" required /></li>
      

      <li><label for="password">Password</label>
      <input class="password" type="text" name="password" required /></li>
     
</ul>
      <button class="reg" onclick="validate()">Register</button>
    </form>
</main>
```

JS

```
//storage key
let STORAGE_KEY ="store-user-reg"


//generate ID
const createId = () =>
  `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)}${new Date().getTime()}`;

//get html elements

  const formEl = {
    id:createId(),
    name: document.querySelector(".name"),
    surname: document.querySelector(".surname").value,
    phone: document.querySelector(".phone").value,
    email: document.querySelector(".email").value,
    password: document.querySelector(".password").value,
  };


//Array for stored registered users
usersArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY)) ?? [];

//function to set local storage
function store(){
  window.localStorage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(usersArray));
}

//register button clicked
function validate() {

let name = formEl.name.value;
let surname = formEl.name.value;
let email = formEl.name.value;
let password = formEl.name.value;


  if (!name) {
    alert("Please fill in name");
  }

  if (!surname) {
    alert("Please fill in Surname");
  }

  if (!email) {
    alert("Please fill in email");
  }

  if (!password) {
    alert("Please create a password");
  }

  usersArray.push(formEl);
  store();
  
}
```

I added screenshots so you can see both errors

[image: Console error]

[image: Local storage issue]
[image: piece of code I am focusing on]

Comment: It doesn't look like you're pushing anything in usersArray.push();

Comment: right I forgot about that, so I tried ``` usersArray.push(formEl);``` still the same issue though. the ```formEl``` would contain the users info when registered

Comment: Perhaps you stored something errant in the `localStorage` while testing and need to clear it. Try removing the key/value from `localStorage` then run your script. I can't reproduce it on `jsfiddle` so I'm guessing you must have something in there that shouldn't be there. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1wkn5x24/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating your `formEl` object on page load, and all the fields will be blank, you need to move your declaration inside of your `validate()` function to actually populate `formEl` with the data you want.

The other issue is what Ryan mentioned, I suggest clearing your local storage.

Updating the validate function to:

```
function validate() {
    const formEl = {
      id: createId(),
      name: document.querySelector(".name").value,
      surname: document.querySelector(".surname").value,
      phone: document.querySelector(".phone").value,
      email: document.querySelector(".email").value,
      password: document.querySelector(".password").value,
    };
    if (!formEl.name) {
      alert("Please fill in name");
    }

    if (!formEl.surname) {
      alert("Please fill in Surname");
    }

    if (!formEl.email) {
      alert("Please fill in email");
    }

    if (!formEl.password) {
      alert("Please create a password");
    }
    usersArray.push(formEl);
    store();
  }
```

should also help!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. This was they issue

```
let name = formEl.name.value;
let surname = formEl.name.value;
let email = formEl.name.value;
let password = formEl.name.value;
```

So I updated the code to this

```
let name = formEl.name;
let surname = formEl.surname;
let email = formEl.email;
let password = formEl.password;
```

which stopped the `1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

only thing left to do now is to figured out why the inputs are seen as empty even though I put in the information

[image]

Comment: see my answer for why the inputs are empty

Comment: Great thank you, did not catch your answer while I was putting in mine.

Comment: no problem! glad you were able to fix part of the issue on your own

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your localStorage. Otherwise `JSON.parse` will continuing parsing that string into `'[object Object]'`. It looks like in a previous attempt you did not stringify the object before calling `setItem`, so it got saved as the string `'"[object Object]"'`. You will need to clear that out in order for it to get reinitialized.

Once clear, your initialization logic should work fine.

Comment: thank you, Raine, managed to sort it out. Thanks for your help